# Azure Devops Services and VPN - encrypt the data

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, azure-devops, vpn

We are about to use Azure devops services (Cloud tfs) and store our code in azure devops git repo

And build the artifacts on hybrid on premise servers.

and we will take the artifacts from the vm to azure devops services and we will make a release and then we will deploy it to the same vm and we will run it on IIS.

- do we need vpn between azure devops services and the vm to drop the artifacts ? (The data encrypt / no you must install vpn on azure and your vm / install vpn on your vm )
- do we need vpn between our computers and connecting to azure devops services to use git (The data encrypt / no you must install vpn on azure and your vm / install vpn on your vm )?

The question is do we need to use the vpn to encrypt our data or it's already encrypted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
do we need vpn between azure devops services and the vm to drop the artifacts ?
```

You need to make sure your VM can be accessed from internet, or you can deploy self-hosted build agent on your VM. Check the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#communication-to-deploy-to-target-servers

> When you use the agent to deploy artifacts to a set of servers, it
> must have "line of sight" connectivity to those servers. The
> Microsoft-hosted agent pools, by default, have connectivity to Azure
> websites and servers running in Azure.
>
> If your on-premises environments do not have connectivity to a
> Microsoft-hosted agent pool (which is typically the case due to
> intermediate firewalls), you'll need to manually configure a
> self-hosted agent on on-premises computer(s). The agents must have
> connectivity to the target on-premises environments, and access to the
> Internet to connect to Azure Pipelines or Team Foundation Server, as
> shown in the following schematic.
>
> [image]

```
do we need vpn between our computers and connecting to azure devops services to use git?
```

Generally, your computers are only required to be able to access internet.

Azure DevOps Services uses Azure's Platform as a Service infrastructure and many of Azure's services, including Azure SQL databases, to deliver a reliable, globally available service for your development projects. We want you to have confidence that your data is being handled appropriately and for legitimate uses. Part of that assurance involves appropriately restricting usage so that your data is used only for legitimate reasons.

Check the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/data-protection?view=azure-devops